# removing child object from an arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, subclass

```
public class FoodStorage{
  ArrayList<Food> foodList = new ArrayList<Food>();

  FoodStorage (ArrayList<Food> foodToStore){
    foodList.addAll(foodToStore);
  }

  public void removeFood(Food food){
    foodList.remove(food);
  }
}

public abstract class Food{
  boolean rotten;
  int daysOld;

  abstract void spoil();
}

public class Meat extends Food(){
}

public class Fruit extends Food{
}

public class Apple extends Fruit{
}

public class Pear extends Fruit{
}
```

If I pass a Fruit object to the removeFood method will it remove the first apple or pear it comes to from  the arraylist because they are also fruit or not? I want the array list to remove the first object that is a any kind of fruit and I figured making fruit concrete rather than abstract might help with this.

Comment: Have you tried running the code to check?

Comment: yes it does not remove the subclass fruit infact creating a new object that you want to remove and calling the remove(Object) method on  an arraylist does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

No, it will search for the **actual object** you are passing and remove it(*). It does not search and remove an object *of the same class or a subclass*.

If the object you are passing does not match any of the ones contained in the ArrayList, it won't remove anything.

On the contrary, if the object you are passing is actually stored in the ArrayList, it will be removed (e.g. the code below removes the Apple object).

```
    ArrayList<Food> fl = new ArrayList<Food>();

    Meat m = new Meat();
    fl.add(m);
    Fruit f=new Fruit();
    fl.add(f);
    Apple a=new Apple();
    fl.add(a);
    Pear p=new Pear();
    fl.add(p);

    Fruit fruit = a;

    FoodStorage fs = new FoodStorage(fl);
    fs.removeFood(fruit);
```

If you want to remove the first object that is an instance of a given class, then you need to implement the code, traversing the ArrayList until finding such object. In that case, I don't think the method should receive a Food object, but the name of the class to search and remove.

Note:

The `ArrayList` `remove` method removes the first occurrence of the specified element from this list, if it is present. If the list does not contain the element, it is unchanged. More formally, removes the element with the lowest index i such that:

- If the passed parameter is null, then removes the first element that is null
- If the passed parameter `o` is not null, then removes the first element such that `o.equals(get(i))`

To remove a specific element, you need to pass either the position of such element (method `remove(int index)`), a reference to the object (method `remove(Object o)`) or a reference to an object such that its equals method returns true when comparing them.

Alternatively, you could also use the method `removeIf(Predicate<? super E> filter)`, which removes all of the elements of this collection that satisfy the given predicate, if it fits better your requests.

Comment: so How would I remove the first object that is of  the same class as the object I want  to remove from an arraylist of objects? Is running a for loop and checking for instanceof then removing the matching element  by index   be the only way?

Comment: yes, you would need to find an object that is an instance of the searched class. I have edited my answer to include this.  In that case I don't think the method should receive a concrete object as parameter, shouldn't it just receive the name of the class?

Comment: this was just a simple  example  in the real project i'm working on each Item / food will have various other attributes such as weight, poison, ect and each man  will  be carrying an arraylist of various items weapons, potions, food gold ect so the item will be needed.  But if I did arrayList.add(new Object()); how would that object be identified in the array list? what would you put into the Arraylist.remove() method to delete it? Or  could that object only be deleted by index?

Comment: arrayList.remove uses the equals method for selecting the object to remove. Maybe you can implement your own remove method or use the removeIf one if it fits better. I have edited my answer to better explain.